# Problems with loop for in ESLint

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with ESLint and I do not know what to do anymore, because without it it does not allow me to move forward. What I'm doing is concatenating the numbers that come to me, for example: ["1", "2"] the output would be: 12

```
    let _sortItem = '';
    for (var p in this.state.sortItem2) {
      _sortItem += this.state.sortItem2[p];
    }
    this._month = '';
    for (var m in this.state.sortItem1) {
      this._month += this.state.sortItem1[m];
    }
```

> ESLint: for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which
>   is virtually never what you want. Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting array. (no-restricted-syntax

How could I make this valid for ESLint? I know there are other questions already but it does not work for me the next code.

```
Object.keys( this.state.sortItem2).forEach(function(p) {
  yield put(setCurrentValue(p, currentValues[p]));
})
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using generator methods in the last example?

Comment: It is what I have tried and in fact I have tried to concatenate in that way with Object Keys but it does not work for me

Comment: The `Object.keys` version seems to have pretty much nothing in common with the `for...of` version. I'm not sure why you consider them equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refactor the first function like so:

```
Object.keys(this.state.sortItem2).forEach(key => {
 _sortItem += this.state.sortItem2[key]
})
```

Now it'll only roll over the properties you assigned to your object rather than all the inherited stuff too.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to put it with put but I did not recognize it and I assigned it to a constant and neither

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is fine, but using `Object.keys` isn't the best solution when you're actually just interested in the values:

```
Object.values(this.state.sortItem2).forEach(value => {
  _sortItem += value;
});
```

Or, with `for .. of`:

```
for (let value of Object.values(this.state.sortItem2)) {
  _sortItem += value;
}
```

Or, more simply:

```
const _sortItem = Object.values(this.state.sortItem2).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just passing by, to keep this question up to date, today you can simply use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (ESLint valid) to do exactly what you want:

```
const _sortItem = this.state.sortItem2.reduce(
    (prev, current) => prev + current,
    '' // default value
);

this._month = this.state.sortItem1.reduce(
    (prev, current) => prev + current,
    '' // default value
);
```

Or you can also use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement instead of for...in to do the same thing:

```
let _sortItem = '';
for (var p of this.state.sortItem2) {
  _sortItem += p;
}

this._month = '';
for (var m of this.state.sortItem1) {
  this._month += m;
}
```